# Java native memory tracking heap committed much more than total from heap dump

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jstat, jcmd

Using `jdk1.8.0_152` I am trying to track down what part of my java program is using the most memory (mainly in the heap)

Using `top` I see that the whole process is using around 1.109G of residual memory

Using `jcmd {PID} VM.native_memory` I see that the total reserved is 4704896 KB and the committed is around 1290820 KB. 
Committed is slightly more than residual memory but I've read that not all committed memory could have been paged to actual memory so I'm not so concerned about that difference

The main concern I have right now is the difference between the heap memory usage from `VM.native_memory` and total heap usage when I use `jcmd {PID} GC.class_histogram`

I've also tried to compare the heap usage using `jstat -gc {PID}` and got results similar to `GC.class_histogram`

According to `GC.class_histogram` and `jstat -gc`, heap usage is around 250MB but using `VM.native_memory` heap usage(committed in the `Java Heap` section) is around 1000000KB (so little less than 1GB) but the actual RSS memory seems to be closer to the total committed in `VM.native_memory`

My guess right now is `VM.native_memory` Java Heap contains memory that has not been garbage collected but even when I run garbage collection, I see that the result of `jstat -gc` decreasing dramatically while `VM.native_memory` isn't affected at all (although I've heard the user manually invoking garbage collection won't always lead to a full garbage collection but it seems at least that `jstat -gc` seems to match the result from `GC.class_histogram`.

Another thing I've heard is residual memory from `top` isn't always freed when the process using the memory frees it until that memory absolutely needs to be freed.

So to sum up

1. Why is `VM.native_memory` showing a different heap memory usage from `jstat` and `GC.class_histogram`?
2. Which metric should I use to make sure how much memory my java process is using? (given that residual memory in `top` might not always reflect the actual usage)

Comment: @Holger according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html native memory seems to refer to all the memory Java Hotspot VM uses, including heap and also other memory such as thread (stack), class caches etc

Comment: I see, so you don’t understand that “committed” does not mean “used” in the sense of “filled with Java objects”?

Comment: @Holger hmm.. yes if I understand you correctly? but according to the documentation it says "Note that only committed memory is actually used." so it seems like committed should be "used". According to how total committed is similar to what `top` says the process is using  it seems like committed should be "used"? (although residual memory might refer to the total memory jvm has locked compared to the memory being actually "filled with objects". But according to the documentation "committed" seems to refer to objects actually filling that memory up")

Comment: Memory that has not been committed, obviously is not used. However, heap memory that has been used, but becomes free due to garbage collection still is committed and will be reused for subsequent allocations. Giving memory back to the system happens rarely, some garbage collectors will never give back.

Comment: @Holger that sounds reasonable as I remember reading about that part... so does that mean native Java Heap memory is always going to be an upper bound on how much memory the process actually uses (and in most cases is an "cumulative sum" of all the objects allocated?) in other words in terms of the actual memory a java process consumes, I should only refer to the heap dump and to the other parts in the native memory tracking (like stack, code, internal etc)? In that case in what scenario would analyzing `committed` be useful?

Comment: The committed RAM doesn’t have to be an upper bound, there might be attempts to commit more when necessary (though, usually there’s at least one garbage collection attempt before trying to commit more). See also [this summary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html#skip.navbar.top).

Answer (score 0):

i guess your jvm heap has been set with a range size.

native memory tracker displays memory size from os view (which is close to `top` command), while `jstat` displays at an inner perspective from jvm.

it means that jvm will request mem from os (check from `top`), but really use it or not depends on itself (check by `jstat` or `jmap`).